# Is there a way to avoid generating "modules" root item from the treeview in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

I love the flexibility module-grouping gives you to customize the document structure. I am wondering if there is any way *(configuration or custom code)* to remove the automatically created "Modules" treeview layer?

```xml
<tab type="modules" visible="Yes" title=""/>
```

[image: current documentation structure]

**Note**: I do not wish to change the title. I wish to remove the layer while keeping its children.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no direct way to do this.
The following is a workaround but I don't know all the implications and side effects.

I did a small test with

```
/// \file

/// @defgroup grp1 First Group
/// the first group

/// @defgroup grp2 Second Group
/// the second group
```

In the file `modules.js` we see:

```
    [ "First Group", "group__grp1.html", null ],
    [ "Second Group", "group__grp2.html", null ]
```

In the file `html/navtreedata.js` we see:

```
    [ "Modules", "modules.html", "modules" ],
```

When we replace this line with

```
    [ "First Group", "group__grp1.html", null ],
    [ "Second Group", "group__grp2.html", null ],
```

it looks like you get the requested result, but this workaround has to be done by hand and as written before the side effects are unknown.

As written by @JPGarza a side effect is:

> if you click on some tree view items it won't remember the selection and the treeview will show a different current page.

Comment: I have removed the accepted answer because I noticed that with this solution if you click on some tree view items it won't remember the selection and the treeview will show a different current page.

Comment: An expected (?) side effect, probably something has to be done in respect to defining when to show the "overall" (here Modules) name in the treeview. It has to be noted though that such a change might also have implications on the "top  blue bar"